# Set a background texture to my osgWidget::frame

Tags: c++, user-interface, openscenegraph

As stated in the title I need to texturize the background of a osgWidget::frame and no matter what I do to it, it does not change from its default white...

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
titleFrame= osgWidget::Frame::createSimpleFrameFromTheme(
    "frame",
    bgTexture,
    5.0f,
    5.0f,
    osgWidget::Frame::FRAME_TEXTURE
    );

titleFrame->getBackground()->setColor( osg::Vec4(1,1,1, 1) );
titleFrame->getBackground()->setTexture( new osg::Texture2D( bgTexture ) );
titleFrame->getBackground()->setTexCoordWrapHorizontal();
```

I tried changing the color with set color to a red one but to no avail.
The only solution I've found so far is to fill it with an empty label. Problem is I need that frame to be able to scroll, and I'll need to constantly add and remove items from it, so the empty label solution isn't very good one.

Also, I've tried to add the frame to the window manager after and before changing the background settings, and it didn't work either.

I should also mention that this frame is embedded in a osgWidget::Box, don't know if that changes anything or not.

Anyway, I'd be grateful if anyone has a solution for this problem.

(BTW is it possible to make a widget unfocusable?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute `title->setFlags(osgWidget::Frame::FrameOptions
::FRAME_TEXTURE)` before `titleFrame->getBackground()->setTexture(image)`.

Otherwise `titleFrame->canTexture()` will return `false`.

// I don't have here the environment to confirm the solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've tried that too, and it still didn't work

I created the frame with this option set: osgWidget::Frame::FRAME_TEXTURE

Answer (score 0):

Try with `titleFrame->getBackground()->setImage(image, true)`.

Comment: Still nothing, unfortunately :(